# Is there a "quick" way to determine that $f(x) = \frac{x^2 - 8x + 7}{|x^2 - 8x + 7|} (2x+ 8) + 2x$ doesn't change signs when crossing $x = 7$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus

Please pardon me if this sounds like a stupid question. I’m from South East Asia where quick analysis is crucial for solving our university entrance exams in time, and I thought this might be one of those areas where my judgment could be optimized.

Consider $g(x) = \frac{x}{|x + 1|}$

$x = 0$ is a solution with multiplicity $1$ to $\text{nominator} = 0 \bigvee \text{denominator} = 0$

$x = -1$ is a solution with multiplicity $2$ to $\text{nominator}= 0 \bigvee \text{denominator} = 0$

If I were to create a table of signs for $g(x)$, I could suppose $x = \infty$ and quickly see that $g(x) > 0$. Since $x = 0$ is a solution of odd multiplicity and $x = -1$ is a solution of even multiplicity (combining results from equations $\text{nominator} = 0$ and $\text{denominator} = 0$), $g(x)$ must change signs over $x = 0$ but does not over $x = -1$. This way, I could easily fill up the sign table.

\begin{array}{c|rrrr} x & -\infty & -1 & 0 & \infty\\ \hline g(x) & - & - & || & + \end{array}

I wondered if it's possible to quickly fill up the sign table for $f(x)$ shown below without through a split analysis for case $x > 7$ or $x < 1$ and for case $1 < x < 7$. In other words, is it trivial to determine that $f(x)$ changes signs over $x = 1$ but doesn't over $x = 7$?

$$f(x) = \frac{x^2 - 8x + 7}{|x^2 - 8x + 7|} (2x+ 8) + 2x$$

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The key for this particular problem is to notice the flip-flop variable $v=\frac{x^{2}-8x+7}{\left|x^{2}-8x+7\right|}$, then

$$
v=
\begin{cases}
-1 & 1 < x < 7 \\
\phantom{-}1 & x< 1 \text{ or } x > 7
\end{cases}
$$

And the original equation can be expressed as:

$$
2x\cdot \left(1+v\right)+ 8\cdot v=
\begin{cases}
-8 & 1<x<7 \\
4x+8 & x<1 \text{ or } x > 7
\end{cases}
$$

From which you can easily see that $f(x)$ changes sign when crossing $x=-2$ and $x=7$.